# Checking visibility and adding a class with jquery/javascript but can't depend on scroll events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to find something similar to the excellent Jquery plugin - [Viewport Checker](http://dirkgroenen.nl/jQuery-viewport-checker/) but that doesn't rely on scroll events. The reason it can't rely on scroll events is I'm also using Fullpage.js set to "autoscroll:true" which then doesn't actually scroll the page it uses 3D translate to move site around. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

The end result of this:
I want to add a few classes onto a `<div>` when that `<div>` enters the viewport.

When I was setting up Viewport Checker this is how I had it configured

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slide_main_paragraph_container').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeInUp', // Class to add to the elements when they are visible
    offset: 100    
    });   
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using slide anchors?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what that is.

I have a <div> with class `.slide_main_paragraph_container` and `.hidden` that I want to have classes `.visible`, `.animated`, and `.fadeInUp` to when the <div> becomes enter the viewport.

Comment: Ok I think I know what you are asking, I am using anchors for each section and you can navigate to specific slides within that section.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [afterSlideLoad](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#afterslideload-anchorlink-index-slideanchor-slideindex) event is the way you'd do this.

```
afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
    var $loadedSlide = $(this),
        $main = $loadedSlide.find('.slide_main_paragraph_container.hidden');

    if ($main.length) {
       $main.removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible animated fadeInUp');
    }
}
```

Comment: I must not be implementing this right. Here's how I have it right now:

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
autoScrolling: true,
anchors:['Home', 'Mobile', 'Lifestyle', 'Street', 'Travel', 'Projects','Connect',],
menu: '#mymenu'
afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
var $loadedSlide = $(this),
$main = $loadedSlide.find('.slide_main_paragraph_container.hidden');
if ($main.length) {
$main.removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible animated fadeInUp');
}
}
}); 
}); 
    </script>`

Comment: Update - if I put in the url and anchor link for a section, the code fires and the <div> shows. But if I navigate down to the same section the code doesn't fire. Check it out - http://www.davidsiglinphotography.com/#Street

Comment: That's an interesting wrinkle and probably a bug that ought to be reported to the FullPage authors.  I'd try manually firing it after a timeout if there's a hash on the location.  `if (window.location.hash.length > 1)`, basically.  You've got a syntax error on your site right now, fyi.